# httpClient.GetAsync(url); awaiting forever

Tags: c#, .net, http

A week ago this code worked for me. Not sure what changed in my environment. Today the httpClient.GetAsync(url); does not finish. It is waiting on something but I have no idea what. I can see in the log that the API responds in 0.037986 (s). Any ideas how I can further isolate the issue? Is there a public ping API perhaps I can try just to make sure the issue  is with my client side code?

```
using (var httpClient = GetHttpClient(authToken))
{
    var url = BuildActionUri(action, parameters);

    var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    try
    {
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    byte[] responseBytes = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    string responseJSON = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    if (responseJSON != "null")
    {
        T result = FACommon.JSON.Parse<T>(responseJSON);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Log Info:
**********Processing Info 372d32dc-036a-43b9-9631-83ae472a5739 for request: /localhost:3000/api/connection**********
---------------------Request user: Admin - Tenant:  - Roles:
---------------------Request params: {}
---------------------Request processing time: 0.037986 (s)
********************************************************************************

Comment: Try using a network sniffer such as Fiddler or Wireshark to see the http traffic from/to your client.

Comment: Is that your api code too? Can you include some of that?

Comment: Are you calling `.Wait()` or `.Result` or something like that up the call stack from the method that contains the code that you've posted?

Comment: Take a look at `netstat` and memory consumption.

Comment: This sounds like a thread deadlock to me. As I don't have all surrounding code, I can not say what causes it. Change your code to this ```var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);```. It should prevent the deadlock. If you want to know more about this: You can read up here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/.